# How do I format a float to have 3 numbers before the decimal

Tags: c, format, decimal

I've figured how to format a float to a max of 3 decimals, but how do I get a float to format 3 places before the decimal
ex:
`Input: 3.524`
`Output: 003.524`

here's an example of what I'm using so far:
`float numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree;`
`scanf("%f %f %f", &numberOne, &numberTwo, &numberThree);`.
`printf("\n%+6.3f\n%+6.3f\n%+6.3f\n", numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree);`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try: `%+08.3f`. The `0` means pad with leading zeroes.  The `8` is because a total of 6 digits is needed and 2 more for `+` and `.`.

Comment: @kaylum thanks! I tried that and it worked just like I needed it to!